# How to show tick box instead of cross in mPDF and PHP

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, mpdf

I am using mPDF plugin for pdf writing with PHP. I want to checked some check boxes and using below code for that.

```
<input checked="checked" value="1" type="checkbox" style="display: inline-block;  margin-top: 10px !important;" />
```

But when pdf created it is showing a cross for the checked checkboxes. What I want to show is a right arrow just like html to show it checked.
It's very necessary to show like that. Also I can't change PDF plugin as it is used at many places.

Edit :

I got that there is some code for that cross in form.php class at line no 405

```
 if (isset($objattr['checked']) && $objattr['checked']) {
            //Round join and cap
            $this->mpdf->SetLineCap(1);
            $this->mpdf->Line($lx,$ty,$rx,$by);
            $this->mpdf->Line($lx,$by,$rx,$ty);
            //Set line cap style back to square
            $this->mpdf->SetLineCap(2);
        }
```

so needs to overwrite it. But with which don't know

Comment: try same but without `style="display: inline-block;  margin-top: 10px !important;" `

Comment: tried but not working :( I found that it is in library that it show the cross for selected checkboxes in class named form.php line no 405

Comment: it ll be better if u use a checked image instead of checkboxes in places. better than hacking the core i mean.

Comment: I think this will be a good option. As I did not get any answer still....:(